# Corner detection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to find corners of the following image:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
im = imread('layer2.png');
BW=im2bw(im, 100/256);
BW=~BW;
figure,imshow(BW);title('Original Image');
C = corner(BW,4);
hold on
plot(C(:,1), C(:,2), 'r.', 'MarkerSize',30);
```

but it detects wrong corners as shown in the following image:

[image]

What is wrong? How can I make it to detect the real corners?

Comment: not sure, but you can try calling corner with 'MinimumEigenvalue'

Comment: I tried that, but it does not detect all of the corners! any other suggestion?

Comment: you can try blurring the image a bit before sending to the corner detector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add one line before `im2bw`:

```
im = imdilate(im,strel('disk',2));
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, can you please explain what this line does?

Comment: @user114781, strel('disk',2) create a disk-shape mask. And I used this mask to smooth the edge a little bit (imdilate, like its name, dilate the bright regions smoothly). Since the size of mask is small, the 4 90 degree corners won't get influenced. Thanks

Comment: I just did that. Thanks agian.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out the cornermetric function in MATLAB which gives you more control over the threshold you want to apply to the corner metric values before selecting final corners.